# Disabling Ruby 3.1.2's auto completion has inadvertently enabled logging of the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ever since upgrading to Ruby 3.1.2, I am now getting a prompt in the rails console that allows for auto completion. While this is nice, it also slows down my typing and heavily interferes with me backspacing, etc. As a result, I have created a file named `.irbrc` and added the following content:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

The only issue that I noticed is now I have a file called `.irb_history`. I've looked up some information about the history, but all I can do is find information about specifying the number of lines I want to have saved; not disable it.

How can I disable the creation and/or storing of my Ruby/Rails commands from being stored in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off saving history with option below:

```rb
# .irbrc
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = false
```

And you can also change location for the history file with the option:

```rb
# .irbrc
IRB.conf[HISTORY_FILE] = "/PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER/.irb-history"
```